# When Adding a product to cart programatically ,the price of the product becomes zero ($0.00)

Tags: magento-1.9, price, addtocart, mini-cart

When  Adding a product to cart programatically ,the price of the product becomes  zero ($0.00) on the fist time , but on adding the same item to the cart, it shows the price .

The product adding is handled by Event observer method on the event "**checkout_cart_add_product_complete**" using the below code.

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');            
$cart->init();
$product_id=1387;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);    
$params = array(
    'product' => $product_id,
    'qty' =>1
    );
$cart->addProduct($product,$params);
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

[image]

Please help me to solve this problem.

But when i go to cart and return to the product page the price shown or when i delete a product in the cart the price shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
$params = array( 'product' => $product_id, 'qty' =>1 )
```

You are programmatically adding it to cart but not specifying the price.

I believe in Magento's structure because you're adding it for the first time it's a custom one that it doesn't recognize till your second add.  Assuming you have a set price in the admin panel for Ice Pack Medium could you try adding in the `$params` array a `'price' => whateverpriceyouwanthere`

Comment: I added the price as array parameter, but still the same result, it shows zero price.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to add product to the cart (basically to the quote)

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quote->addProduct($product, $qty);
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

Where `$product` is an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`

Answer (score 0):

tested  code and working without any problem

```
  $product_id=1387;
  $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
  $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
  $cart->init();
  $cart->addProduct($_product, array('qty' => 1));    
  $cart->save();
```

Comment: The problem is probably that it's called from this specific observer.

Comment: Yes the problem is related to the event  checkout_cart_add_product_complete .

Comment: On which event you trigger the observer to add product to cart? can you provide the code?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason totals collection is not triggered *by your code*. As soon as you visit the cart page or add another product, totals are collected again and everything looks right.

The problem with your code seems to be that you are initializing a new cart object, there is probably a conflict with the already instantiated cart object .

Try to replace the first two lines with

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
```